# replacing a value withgsub in lua

Tags: lua, gsub

```
function expandVars(tmpl,t)  
      return (tmpl:gsub('%$([%a ][%w ]+)', t)) end
 local sentence = expandVars("The $adj $char1 looks at you and says, $name, you are $result", {adj="glorious", name="Jayant", result="the Overlord", char1="King"}) 
   print(sentence)
```

The above code work only when I have ',' after the variable name like, in above sentence it work for $ name and $ result but not for $adj and $char1, Why is that ?

Comment: Are spaces allowed in variables' names?  If not, try `%$(%a%w*)`

Comment: Oh, yes! It worked. But, how is [%a][%w] different from %a%w ? Please ?

Comment: `[%w ]` means alphanumeric symbols **or space**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**:

Your pattern `[%a ][%w ]+` means a letter or space, followed by at least one letter or number or space. Since regexp is greedy, it will try to match as large a sequence as possible, and the match will include the space:

```
function expandVars(tmpl,t)  
    return string.gsub(tmpl, '%$([%a ][%w ]+)', t)
end

local sentence = expandVars(
    "$a1 $b and c $d e f ", 
    {["a1 "]="(match is 'a1 ')", ["b and c "]="(match is 'b and c ')", ["d e f "]="(match is 'd e f ')", }
)
```

This prints

> (match is 'a1 ')(match is 'b and c ')(match is 'd e f ')

**Solution**:

The variable names must match keys from your table; you could accepts keys that have spaces and all sort of characters but then you are forcing the user to use `[]` in the table keys, as done above, this is not very nice :)

Better keep it to alphanumeric and underscore, with the constraint that it cannot start with a number. This means to be generic you want a letter (`%a`), followed by any number of (including none) (`*` rather than `+`) of alphanumeric and underscore `[%w_]`:

```
function expandVars(tmpl,t)  
    return string.gsub(tmpl, '%$(%a[%w_]*)', t)
end

local sentence = expandVars(
    "$a $b1 and c $d_2 e f ", 
    {a="(match is 'a')", b1="(match is 'b1')", d_2="(match is 'd_2')", }
) 

print(sentence)
```

This prints

> (match is 'a') (match is 'b1') and c (match is 'd_2') e f; non-matchable: $_a $1a b

which shows how the leading underscore and leading digit were not accepted.

Comment: @Simrankaur Np. Since you have the points, dont' forget to upvote if it was useful (not just answers to your questions, but any SO answer you find useful or question you find tricky).

Comment: I would love to do that, but I can upvote comments only, right? not the answers?Let me know if I can

Comment: @Simrankaur Only need 15 points to upvote answers. At over 300 rep you better get started! :) You can look at the questions you posted and go back to upvote the most useful answers in each one.  Then go back to answers you have provided and upvote those questions which are useful (i.e. you learnt something as a result of that question having been asked - even if this in large part due answers given). Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks , I just never noticed the upvote symbol for answers , Thanks for letting me know.I will make sure that i do!